# How to get pixel (or point) color on the TI84+CE

Tags: ti-basic

I can't find a way to do that, and it is essential for my code.

I tried pxl-Test, but it just says if the pixel is on or off

is there a function to look at the memory and find the pixel color?
I am suprised there is no easy way to do that